# Why is equipartition law called a theorem too, in some books?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, soft-question, conventions, history

In some books, the equipartition law is called a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem).

But a law is an observation, and *cannot* be proved. On the other hand, a theorem is something established using earlier assertions.

So what is the history, actually?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (v2) as off-topic because it is about inessential naming tradition rather than physics.

Comment: Seriously? @Qmechanic

Comment: So a concept being a law or a theorem is a naming tradition? I think, this difference is so significant, that it can affect a whole theory

Comment: I wanted to answer, but the question was closed, in any case in a properly sense, is a corollary at all beacause is a direcr consequence of the following equality, that can be proved: $$\left\langle x_{i} \frac{\partial H }{\partial x_{j}}\right\rangle = \delta_{i j} k_{b} T$$ If the quesstion will be opened another time, i will give to you the demonstration and an example.

Comment: I disagree with this closure. There are nontrivial physics underlying this choice of terminology, and it falls in the site scope to explain them.

Comment: It seems to me that this falls under [point 3 Qmechanics gives](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/25301) about notation/terminology question, which directs OP to [hsm.se] for posting this type of query.

Comment: If you assume that the axioms (i.e. laws) of classical mechanics are correct, then equipartition follows as a theorem. This is interesting historically because equipartition was *not* observed in practice due to quantum effects, which helped lead to the development of quantum mechanics.